# End-user specific components with .NET and ClickOnce

Tags: .net, dll, deployment, clickonce

We have a .NET/WPF application we intend to deploy using ClickOnce to multiple end-users. In the application we need to read data from a number of other application databases, like accounting databases etc. (not controlled by us) used by our end user. These external application databases can be different from each other so we cant just incorporate code directly into our application to connect and read those databases. Basically, we need to deploy to every end-user a slightly different application.

Question: What is the preferred way to do that assuming we use ClickOnce as deployment method?

My initial thinking was to have a unique custom dll component that we ship to every end-user. The dll would hold the code to read the specific end user's database and return data to the main application (main application then being exactly the same for every end user).
We also must be able to modify any of those end-user specific dll's in case the end user decides to change their database.

I'd like to have some guidelines/suggestions.

Comment: Are the different user databases the same structure and data, or is the data access completely different for each customer?

Answer (score 0):

we had very similar project - and we ended up with displaying a dialog on first run asking user to enter connection string to the database. And then save that data into local config file.

In my opinion, emailing connection string is much easier than shipping custom DLL to each client.